# Application_Error doesn't triggers at Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, routes

I have the following code in my Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Error()
{
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();
    Response.Clear();
    Server.ClearError();

    //processing

    Response.RedirectPermanent("url processed"));
}
```

At localhost this works fine, doing something like this:

I access to "www.somesite.com/uk/en-GB", and because this route isn't registered the Application_Error "catch" the error, process it and redirect to the correct route "www.somesite.com/en-GB". (As shown in the code above at Global.asax)

But at the server, I try to access to "www.somesite.com/uk/en-GB", and it don't goes to Application_Error, instead of that show me this error:

[image: http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86d7d7d970b-pi]

Anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Start fiddler, check the traffic between you and the server, I guess that it reaches Application_Error and redirects to a URL that's invalid for some reason. See what fiddler gives you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't get an error.  You got a 404 response code.  You'll need to handle that scenario differently. The Application_Error only catches uncaught exceptions.

Comment: Completely incorrect statement, 404 errors will also trigger Application_Error.

Comment: @EdDeGagne So what's the conclusion?

Comment: I guess my first question is the line: Response.RedirectPermanent("url processed")

What is "url processed" ?? I believe that string value is supposed to be a valid url.

Comment: Yes of course it is. It's like, I try to access to "www.somesite.com/uk/en-GB", and because this is an invalid route, the Application_Error catch that and process the url to "www.somesite.com/en-GB", and redirect to there. But this only happens at localhost... At server (IIS 6) the Application_Error doesn't catch that and shows that picture above....

Answer (score 0):

I'm running IIS 6 and I found that this problem was easily fixed with adding this to my Web.Config file under system.web:

```
    <customErrors mode="Off">
    </customErrors>
```

This will allow the code in Application_Error to execute.